# How do I parse Array within Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to parse information that is inside an Array. The array comes from an RSS feed that I have converted into a json. The array is:

```
<channel>
<item>
    <title> Title A </title>
    <description> Description A </description>
    <stuff url="google.com" type="search engine">
</item>

<item>
    <title> Title B </title>
    <description> Description B </description>
    <stuff url="yahoo.com" type="old stuff">
</item>
....

</channel>
```

I am parsing using something like:

```
$newsoutput = json_decode(json_encode($the_RSS_Link), TRUE);

foreach ($newsoutput['channel']['item'] as $item) {
   echo $item['title'];
   echo "<br>";
   echo $item['description'];
   echo "<br>";
   echo $item['stuff']['url'];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

I can get both "title" and "description"; but I cannot extract the "url" values inside "stuff". I have tried various combinations without luck

Please advise.

Thank you,

H.

Comment: I think you will have to process that XML using an XML parser in order to access the attributes of `stuff`

Comment: @Hernandito can you post the json too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tested and working example which requires the use of `simplexml_load_string()`

```php
<?php
$raw = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Title A</title>
            <description>Description A</description>
            <stuff url="google.com" type="search engine"></stuff>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>Title B</title>
            <description>Description B</description>
            <stuff url="yahoo.com" type="old stuff"></stuff>
        </item>
    </channel>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($raw);
$newsoutput = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);

foreach ($newsoutput['channel']['item'] as $item) {
    echo $item['title'];
    echo "<br>\n";
    echo $item['description'];
    echo "<br>\n";
    echo $item['stuff']['@attributes']['url'];
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Title A<br>
Description A<br>
google.com<br>
Title B<br>
Description B<br>
yahoo.com<br>
```

Be careful, the XML document you gave us was invalid and I had to close the  tag.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu... The @attributes is what I was missing. Problem solved! Thank you again.

Comment: Why `json_decode(json_encode`? Why not just access them via the SimpleXML that already makes them accessible?

Comment: It does, but it was to stick to the original code as much as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "It does"?

Comment: It does make sense to avoid the double json encode/decode. Sorry if it was unclear!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have valid XML (which you should if it is a valid RSS fee) you can use the SimpleXML parser:

```
$xml = '<channel>
<item>
    <title> Title A </title>
    <description> Description A </description>
    <stuff url="google.com" type="search engine"/>
</item>

<item>
    <title> Title B </title>
    <description> Description B </description>
    <stuff url="yahoo.com" type="old stuff"/>
</item></channel>';
$x = new simplexmlelement($xml);
foreach($x->item as $item){
    echo $item->title . ' ' . $item->stuff['url'] . ' ' . $item->stuff['type'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/6ICrG

Note the `stuff` element here has been modified so it is self-closing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I went with Mathieu's solution below as it required less re-coding from what I had done.

Comment: @Hernandito Okay, doesn't really make sense to me. Why encode to decode? The SimpleXML has all the information already..

Answer (score 0):

If the RSS content is like the one you posted on the example you should parse RSS feed using XML parser instead of using json_* functions.

Here are some simple examples using SimpleXML https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks Tom...I will use this for reference.